# Code showing "dereferencing null ptr" even though a cout of the pointer points to a memory address. _malloca is used to allocate memory

Tags: c++, allocation

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int v = 2;
    int* arr = (int*)_malloca(v * sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 200; //shows dereferencing null ptr
    std::cout << *arr;
}
```

I have used `_malloca()` to do memory allocation of dynamic array on the stack (I know vector is there, I just wanted to experiment with _malloca). I just wanted to know how it works but unlike `new` this gives a dereferencing warning and it is not causing runtime error here. The `arr` has a memory address and even takes in values and prints them. What am I missing?

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Comment: What exactly "shows dereferencing null ptr"? Your IDE? A static analyzer?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica okay i added the screenshot of my visual studio.

Comment: It's a warning.  `_malloca` can return NULL if the allocation fails, and your code doesn't test for this.  It's saying it *might* dereference a null pointer.

Comment: By the way, you should also be calling `_freea` to deallocate the memory when done.

Comment: @NateEldredge oh okay makes sense. Thank you. I'm quite new to stack overflow, so should I answer the question myself by updating the code/delete/leave it like this? Please give a suggestion.

Comment: Answer it using the "Answer your question" button.

Comment: Why are you using the non-standard `_malloca()` and (if you release) `_free()`?   As distinct from using operators `new` and `delete` (standard C++) or `malloc()` and `free()` (standard C, supported by C++).

Comment: @Peter I am just experimenting. Just was trying to understand _malloca.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is given by @NateEldredge

> It's a warning. `_malloca` can return `NULL` if the allocation fails, and your code doesn't test for this. It's saying it might dereference a null pointer.

So I added an if statement to check for `NULL`. Also, in debug mode `_malloca` always allocates memory in the heap. So, also check the code in release mode.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int v = 4;
    int* arr = (int*)_malloca(v * sizeof(int));
    if(arr != NULL) //a check is required if _malloca was able to allocate memory
        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = i * 2;
            std::cout << arr[i]<<"\n";
        }
    _freea(arr); //freeing the memory 
}
```